# Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)

Tags: arrays, typescript, methods, next.js, react-typescript

I use VSCode, React/NextJS and Typescript on a windows machine.

A cat jumped on my laptop. After the cat left, I suddenly had my Typescript telling me that all the array methods do not exist.

Please see below code for the errors

Edit: Adding example code

```
const hello = ["hi", "hi2", "hi3"]

if (hello.length > 2){
    console.log("hi")
}
Error: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)




const arrray = ["hi", "hi2", "hi3"]

const why = arrray[1]
Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '1' can't be used to index type 'string[]'.
  Property '1' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(7053)

typing arrray. in VSCode gives me 8 options, copyWithin, entries, fill, find, findIndex, flat, flatMap, includes
```

Comment: can you post sample code please?

Comment: Try to open the command palette. Mac: Cmd + Shift + P. Win: Ctrl + Shift + P, then search for "Restart TS server", click enter and see if that does the trick

Comment: @Stanleyy didn't work :((

Comment: @Ben Clayton 

Example code:
`const array = ["one", "two", "three"]

const ln = array.length()`

Error message: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)
This is on a freshly restarted/opened vsconsole

Comment: Another info: 

When I type `array.` to see which methods are available, there are 8 total. They are 
"copyWithin, entries, fill, find, findIndex, flat, flatMap, and includes".  There are no other

Comment: `array.length()` shouldn't be `.length`? that's not a function

Comment: and about the second issue: does this change anything?  `const arrray: string[] = ["hi", "hi2", "hi3"];`

Comment: oh yea! let me give the real example code one sec

Comment: No change :(

`if (process.argv.length < 3 || process.argv.length > 4) {
  logger.error("ts-node addInvitation [userType (user | creator)] [--dry | undefined]")
  logger.debug(process.argv)
  exit()
}
Error: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)
`

Comment: Here's a simpler version

`const hello = ["hi", "hi2", "hi3"]

if (hello.length > 2){
    console.log("hi")
}
Error: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Big red switch time?

Comment: what would be the big red switch...? @500-InternalServerError

Comment: Restart the computer - or at least VS Code.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I have tried both, including reinstalling vs code

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it seems that I had to update VSCode. strange

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I found the fix - All I had to do was to update my VSCode to the newest version.

It seems like everything is ok now. It also fixed other bugs I've had for some time.

But why would a cat cause this?